# Using Hello.js with angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, hello.js

I just want to use hello.js with angular 4 with specific server (private url).

Is-there angular module to do that ?

I have try to use ngx-hellojs but there is an error on chrome :

```
hello.all.js:1 Uncaught Error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed
    at Object.eval (hello.all.js:1)
    at Object.1.2 (hello.all.js:1)
    at o (hello.all.js:1)
    at eval (hello.all.js:1)
    at Object.347.1 (hello.all.js:1)
    at o (hello.all.js:1)
    at t (hello.all.js:1)
    at eval (hello.all.js:1)
    at eval (hello.all.js:1)
    at Object.eval (hello.all.js:1)
```

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use ngx-hellojs

Install using **npm install ngx-hellojs**

Edit .angular-cli.json

```
{
  //...
  "apps": [
    {
      //...
      "scripts": [
        //...
        "../node_modules/hellojs/dist/hello.all.js"
      ],
      //...
    }
  ],
  //...
}
```